# xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token) python3?

Tags: python, xml

I have this code on my python3 for E2 (dreambox)

```
from xml.dom import Node, minidom
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
selectedserverurl = 'http://fairbird.liveblog365.com/TSpanel/TSipanel.xml'

def downloadxmlpage():
        req = Request(selectedserverurl)
        response = urlopen(req)
        data = response.read()
        response.close()
        print("data:",data)
        gotPageLoad(data)
        print("gotPageLoad(data):", gotPageLoad(data))

def gotPageLoad(data = None):
        if data != None:
            xmlparse = minidom.parseString(data)
            for plugins in xmlparse.getElementsByTagName('plugins'):
                item = plugins.getAttribute('cont')
                if 'TSpanel' in item:
                    for plugin in plugins.getElementsByTagName('plugin'):
                        tsitem = plugin.getAttribute('name')
                        print("tsitem:", tsitem)

downloadxmlpage()
```

I have try to read this file and extract the content from it
http://fairbird.liveblog365.com/TSpanel/TSipanel.xml

But I have got this error !!

```
data: b'<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("55cc7e99e3f798b6063f25e8b0f8aa76");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://fairbird.liveblog365.com/TSpanel/TSipanel.xml?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raed/Desktop/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    downloadxmlpage()
  File "/home/raed/Desktop/test.py", line 11, in downloadxmlpage
    gotPageLoad(data)
  File "/home/raed/Desktop/test.py", line 16, in gotPageLoad
    xmlparse = minidom.parseString(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 2000, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 222
```

So How to solve this issue ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` output is HTML, not an XML file, therefore the parser is failing.

The HTML redirects to `http://fairbird.liveblog365.com/TSpanel/TSipanel.xml?i=1` using Javascript, as shown - `This site requires Javascript to work`.

This is typically done to *prevent* anyone from scraping the page/server-files.

Comment: @OneCricketeer.I think the hosting as they wrote here give html data not xml ...https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/this-site-requires-javascript-to-work-please-enable-javascript-in-your-browser-or-use-a-browser-with-javascript-support/18309 ... So How can I convert the html date from TSipanel.xml to xml ?!!!

Comment: Like I said, web server hosts documents this way to prevent exactly what you're trying to do. There isn't much point to attempt to bypass it...

Comment: @OneCricketeer.Thank you very much !! Do you know any free web hosting works with xml and php ?!!

Comment: Unclear why you need PHP just for a file server

Comment: Yes .. I need for my image panel ... python codes depend on xml file not html .. I was change the web hosting to other one can be generate xml fle data .. But if you have way to convert html data to xml your welcome thank you.

Comment: There's nothing that needs converted. You can download files directly from a file server without html pages if you're just interested in hosting static assets. XML isn't relevant. It's simply a file. Even using `curl`  on the link in your question, I get `empty reply from server`, so that only shows that nothing but a browser will work. You could use Selenium in Python to start a "fake" browser, **then** get the file. Or, if that's your server you control, then you don't need PHP to host a file server